# Active Directory Import with Trusted Domain (One way)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, active-directory-import, trusted-domain

We have SharePoint installed on servers joined to domain lets say `contoso.com` and we have users in `Foo.com` with one-way trust with contoso.com. Now Is it possible to sync users from Foo.com to User Profile service using AD import? I don't want to sync users from `contoso.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AD import option does not support multi-Forest scenarios such as:

If you have a trust between two forests, the trusted forest objects will not be imported.

If you need to import users from multiple domain, you must create multiple synchronization connections. If you have multiple domains to manage, using Profile Synchronization or FIM may be a better option.

Refer to the following article about configuring profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server 2013:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Besides, the synchronization account for a connection to Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) must have the Replicate Directory Changes permission on the domain.

Refer to the following article about plan account permissions:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925.aspx#permission